# Random Order by Group in Random Order

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I have 5 tables in mysql forming 4 one to many relationships.  The tables are last_name, parent, child, grandchild, and city.  Last name has many parents, parent has many children, child has many grandchildren, and city has many grandchildren.

I'm needing to get the grandchildren(in a certain city) in a random order but grouped by  last_name(that is, on different rows but consecutively) but with last_name in random order.  So basically.

```
Last_name     GrandChild
    B            3
    B            56
    B            9
    D            2
    D            67
    C            38
    C            20
    A            14
```

I have this so far

```
 SELECT ln.id, gc.id
        FROM parent p
        INNER JOIN child ch
        ON ch.parent_id = p.id
        INNER JOIN grandchild gc
        ON ch.id = gc.child_id
        WHERE gc.city_id = 3
```

That just gives me the layout and relationships I need, but I'm not sure where to go from there.  Is this possible? And if so, what commands/techniques do I need to look into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by "grouped" you mean that you want each grandchild on a separate line, but all with the same last name on consecutive rows.

```
    SELECT ln.id, gc.id
    FROM parent p INNER JOIN
         child ch
         ON ch.parent_id = p.id INNER JOIN
         grandchild gc
         ON ch.id = gc.child_id inner join
         (select ln.*, rand() as rand
          from lastname ln
         ) ln
         on p.lastname = ln.lastname
    WHERE gc.city_id = 3
    order by ln.rand
```

In other words, this assigns a random number to the last name, and then uses it for the order by.  By the way, your request is ambiguous.  If you want the ordering by parent rather than last name, you would do the subquery on parent.

Comment: Nice. I think the OP needs: `order by ln.rand, RAND()`

Comment: Omg Awesome!  Not only for the query but also for explaining what it does.  I had to get the grandchildren also in a random order, so I just wrapped grandchildren the same way you wrapped last name.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT gc.lastname, group_concat(p.lastname) as grandchildren
    FROM parent p
    INNER JOIN child ch ON ch.parent_id = p.id
    INNER JOIN grandchild gc ON ch.id = gc.child_id
    WHERE gc.city_id = 3
    group by gc.lastname
```